# Gstreamer rtmpsink to Azure Media Services live pass through event

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, rtmp, azure-media-services

I am trying to use an on-prem **gstreamer** encoder pipeline to broadcast live video into **Azure Media Services**.

Testing the pipe using the `videotestsrc` seems to be working fine with the folowing string:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 ! flvmux streamable=true ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://xxxx.media.azure.net:1935/live/xxxx/mystream live=true flashver=FMLE/3.0(compatible;FMSc/1.0)'
```

And I'm able to watch the preview of the stream in the Azure AMS dashboard.

Now, if I try to use `appsrc` pipe from my python script using **OpenCV** (compiled with gstreamer support), nothing is showing in the preview window. However an asset is being created for the stream, and I am able to view this asset streaming through the AMS services.

The following **python3** script is using a custom build of OpenCV version 4.0.0 with gstreamer and cuda compiled.

```
import sys
import time
import urllib
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


TEST_CARD = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png'
HEADLINE = 'AZURE LIVE STREAM'

RTMP_SERVER = 'rtmp://xxxx.media.azure.net:1935/live/xxxx/mystream'
GST_PIPE = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 ! flvmux streamable=true ! rtmpsink location='{0} live=true flashver=FMLE/3.0(compatible;FMSc/1.0)' ".format(RTMP_SERVER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('Azure Mediastream tester')
    print(sys.version)
    print (cv2.getBuildInformation())

    imgRequest = urllib.request.urlopen(TEST_CARD)
    imgArray = np.asarray(bytearray(imgRequest.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
    imgO = cv2.imdecode(imgArray, -1)

    h,w,c = imgO.shape
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    line = cv2.LINE_AA
    cv2.putText(imgO,HEADLINE,(302,85),font,1,(255,255,255),2,line)

    print(HEADLINE)
    print ('Showing: {0} at [h:{1},w:{2},c:{3}]'.format(TEST_CARD,h,w,c))
    print ('Opening GSTREAM {0}'.format(GST_PIPE))

    try:
        fcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc ('X','2','6','4')
        stream = cv2.VideoWriter(GST_PIPE,fcc,25.0,(w,h))
        while True:
            currentTime = datetime.now()
            img = imgO.copy()
            cv2.putText(img,str(currentTime),(283,460),font,1,(255,255,255),1,line)

            stream.write(img)
            cv2.imshow(HEADLINE,img)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    finally:
        stream.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print ('DONE')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: We will need details (Media Services account name, Channel ID or LiveEvent name, the region used, approximate time/date/timestamp when you sent the live feed into the service, and perhaps the URL for viewing the stream) to investigate. You could either contact us directly via amshelp@microsoft.com, or, open a support ticket via the Azure Portal. Thanks

Comment: So I sent more details to "amshelp", but would also like to share some more here.

When pressing the "Watch" button in the AMS Dashboard for the live event; - the Media player shows an error, with the following message:

    The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support. (0x20400003)

I have tried several different browsers (Firefox, Edge and Chrome) on multiple computers and OSes. With the same result. The strange thing is that the gst-launch-1.0 pipeline works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after an extensive dialog with **Azure Media Services** team from Microsoft, it turns out that the **Azure Media Player**, requires a sound track to be present for it to be able to play back.

Changing the *GST_PIPE* to:

```
GST_PIPE = "appsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location='{0} live=true flashver=FMLE/3.0(compatibble;FMSc/1.0)' audiotestsrc is-live=true ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! voaacenc bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4 ! mux.".format(RTMP_SERVER)
```

In my **Python** code, made everything work as expected (except the channel preview panel in the Azure portal (still don't know what's going on there)).